# javascript - Fill the value attribute of an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I am trying to make a simple webapp.
I want to put data from the main page into an input box on another window/tab but the input box is always empty when I'm opening it.

Here's the code:
**global.js**

```
function showUserInfo(event) {

// Prevent Link from Firing
event.preventDefault();

var _id = $(this).attr('rel');
var arrayPosition = userListData.map(function(arrayItem) { return    arrayItem._id; }).indexOf(_id);

// Get our User Object
var thisUserObject = userListData[arrayPosition];
window.open('http://localhost:3000/editrecord', 'window', 'width=500,height=400');
var fName = thisUserObject.cName
$("#inputecName").attr('value', fname);
```

Running this would open the 'editrecord' window and the data I am trying to get should be in the input box in 'editrecord' page.

**editrecord.jade**

```
#editBox
     fieldset
          input#inputecName(type='text', placeholder='Customer Name', width = '50%')
          br
          button#btnEditRec(type='submit') Update Record
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show relevant code in OP

Comment: Is your app is static or dynamic?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed enter. :P

Comment: You are calling `$("#inputecName").attr('value', fname);` at current page, though `$#inputecName` appears to be at newly opened `window`? Also, why name the newly opened `window` `"window"`?

Comment: Change `$("#inputecName").attr('value', fname);` to `$("#inputecName").val(fname);` - Use `val()`

Comment: It should open the window first.

Comment: @ShaunakD Sorry, but it is not working.

Comment: why use server side scripting for this example in php use the session variable and in the second page use `.val()` to assign the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`js` at Question attempts to set the `value` of an element at a separate `document`

```
$("#inputecName").attr('value', fname);
```

from the current `document`, without referencing that the element is within a separate `document` at a separate `window`.

You can use `sessionStorage` to access `Storage` object between browsing contexts, or `window` objects, that have same origin; utilize `.ready()` to check `sessionStorage` when `editrecord.html` is opened in browser and the `document` is loaded.

At original `html` document `global.js`

```
<script>
  sessionStorage.setItem("id", 123);
  var w = window.open("editrecord.html", "w");
</script>
```

at `editrecord.html`

```
   <head>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        if (sessionStorage.id) {
          $("#inputecName").val(sessionStorage.getItem("id"))
        }
      })
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="inputecName" />
  </body>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/7TRQOPYPX4bMpxr6pjyX?p=preview

Comment: sorry to ask this but, what does the ' if (sessionStorage.id) ' condition do?

Comment: @JoseBonifacio Checks if `sessionStorage` has a property `id`, which would have been set by the opening `window`. That portion of `js` can be removed; approach attempts to set the `value` of `input` only if `sessionStorage` `id` is set. For example, if `editrecords.html` was opened by user before original `html` document which sets `sessionStorage` and opens document using `window.open()`. The `if` could alternatively be composed `if (sessionStorage.getItem("id") !== null`)`

Answer (score 0):

You can send data via URL like,

```
<a href="nextPage.html?data=blah">Next page</a>
```

By `JS` or Server side script you can fetch the `data` from URL and use it,

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this one

```
var childWindow = window.open('http://localhost:3000/editrecord', 'window', 'width=500,height=400');


$(childWindow.document).load(function() {

    var fName = thisUserObject.cName
    $("#inputecName").attr('value', fname);
})
```

You can access the `inputecName` from chilld window using plain javascript

```
childWindow.document.inputecName
```

Comment: I tried putting a random string instead of 'fname' and even that is not working.